# gdb how to inspect 2D array elements

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, multidimensional-array

I was happily debugging in GDB and then I hit a 2D array that might hold incorrect values.
However I cant seem to be able to print an single element.

```
p array2D[0][0]
```

gives me

> Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete types, try casting to a known type, or void *.

I tried to google this but I can't find anything and I am not sure if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to act on a pointer referencing a module internal definition. Could you provide the declaration of `array2D`?

Comment: What is the type of p ??

Comment: `p` is the print command used in `gdb`, isn't it?

Comment: specifically, what type does gdb think `array2D` is? find out with `ptype array2D`

Comment: I've got my answer. I was using a variable (which stayed constant btw) instead of #define for one of indexes. Compiler must have done something weird with the code. If I use #define i can view it by: p array2D[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

`p arr[0][0]` works for me  my test code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[3][3];
  a[0][0]=1;
  a[0][1]=2;
  return 0;
}
```

on gdb:

```
(gdb) b test.c:6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400473: file test.c, line 6.
(gdb) r
Starting program: a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:6
6       a[0][1]=2;
(gdb) p a[0][0]
$1 = 1
(gdb) ptype a
type = int [3][3]
```

so its not `p arr[0][0]` which is the problem but something else.